# problem in analysis

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis

Find an element in $c_{0}$ which does not belong to $l^{p}$ for $1\leq p < \infty.$

Comment: What are your thoughts on the question?  What have you tried?

Comment: Also, note that $c_0 \subset \ell^\infty$, so you probably miscopied: it should be $1 \leq p < \infty$.

Comment: yes,last inequality is strict....sorry.

Comment: Okay, now what about the other comment?

Comment: Note that on this site, there is an expectation that questions should be asked [together with some context](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: Hint: Cough... logarithm.

Answer (score 2):

Hint. In other words find a real sequence $\{a_n\}_{n\geq 1}$ such that $a_n\to 0$, and
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|a_n|^p=+\infty$$
for all $p\geq 1$. Since $a_n=1/n^r$ with $r>0$ does not work, you need a sequence which goes to zero more slowly.

Comment: If r=1/p then result hold.

Comment: @Robert Z No. The sequence should not belong to ALL $l^p$, with $p\geq 1$.